# Check text input is empty failed if I enter more than one space

Tags: react-native

I am using TextInput from react-native. Here I not need to allow if the user enters more than one space. Below is the code. For empty spaces it allows the user to proceed the submit

Refer code [here](https://snack.expo.io/@aboutreact/check-empty-textinput-example?session_id=snack-session-45GVESXWi)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trim()` function to delete extra spaces in the beginning and the end of a string. Change your conditions like this:

```
if (this.state.TextInputName.trim() != '')
```

And

```
if (this.state.TextInputEmail.trim() != '')
```

[More on usage of trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)